# Javascript library to draw 2D shapes and pan and zoom

Tags: javascript, node.js

Imagine something like Pascals triangle, made up of many circles, with a number written on each circle.

This Pascal's triangle might be 200 rows or more, which obviously wont fit on screen.

As such, I need a JavaScript library to draw circles (in a triangle formation) and pan and zoom around Pascals triangle.

I'm not sure if an SVG library is best or canvas or something else. I'm open to suggestions. Anyone know of a good JavaScript lib? npm modules are fine too.

Help much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion for custom javascript drawings is d3.js.

As an example, http://bl.ocks.org/edrex/1920883 shows a way to draw pascal's triangle.

https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom shows how to do some zoom/pan activities.

This library also makes it possible to render in svg or canvas, depending on your needs.

Comment: awesome answer - previously I was using SVG.js which is a nice library but one of its functions was too slow - switching to D3 fixed the performance issue - I am also going to try d3-zoom over my current solution svg-pan-zoom - I have no complaints with svg-pan-zoom but d3-zoom is far more popular so worth a look - many many thanks